# I use send() but select() is blocking in writefds

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

In readfds works fine. I just can't put send to work. Blocks at last line, select().

````
SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);
fd_set master;
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_SET(listening, &master);
while(true){
        string userInput;
        fd_set copy = master;
        userInput = "test";

        send(copy.fd_array[0], userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
        
        int socketCount = select(0, nullptr, &copy, nullptr, nullptr);

}```
````

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?  You appear to be trying to `send` data to a listening but unconnected TCP socket.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: This is part of the server. The problem here is, if I use writefds instead of readfds doesn't work. And I don't know why. Maybe because I'm listening on the server instead of connecting? I thought writefds was used for send(), but , seems readfds works too @G.M.

Comment: Typically you would call `select()` before calling `send()`, to find out if the socket has buffer-space available to write to, or block until it does have some space available.  Calling `select()` after calling `send()` doesn't make a whole lot of sense (and calling `send()` on a socket that isn't connected to a remote peer makes even less sense -- there's nobody to send to?)